# regular expression to match all characters between {{ and }}

Tags: regex

I am trying to match all links described by this `{{Anchor Text|example.com}}`
 in a string.

I tried with `/{{.*}}/g`, but it only works if it has one link. If there are more such links, it matches the whole string from the first `'{{'` to the last `'}}'`, no matter how many links I have.

For example:

Some text

```
{{link1|example.com}} some text {{link2|example.net}}
```

matches

```
{{link1|example.com}} some text {{link2|example.net}}
```

but not array of matches:

```
[ {{link1|example.com}}, {{link2|example.com}} ]
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need in this particular case - is to use non-greedy (lazy) modifier `?` in your regular expression:

```
/{{.*?}}/g
```

Greedy regular expression tries to match as much symbols as possible, and by default expressions are greedy in most implementations of regular expressions.